# If we know two of the angles between three lines in space can we figure out the third one?

Tags: geometry

There will be a total of three angles between three lines in **space(in 3D)**.If we know two of them,how can we figure out the third one?

PLEASE also give a derivation for the formula.

Comment: I doubt you can.

Comment: do you have an absolute angle or an oriented object? (such that the rotation axis would be restorable)

Comment: I think perhaps in both cases we can compute.

Comment: What kind of configurations are the lines in? In my head, it only makes sense to talk about an angle between two lines if they cross, so as far as I can see, these three lines necessarily have to lie in a common plane and form a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Think on two angles sharing a side. You can turn one of the angles around this side, so the angle you want to compute can be anything.

Your question is like this one: "If we know two sides of a triangle, can we figure out the third one?". The answer is no, because two sides don't determine the third.

Comment: keeping the two known angles as constant, we cant turn the computing angle around any side.By doing so at least one of the constant angles gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for instance, equilateral $\triangle ABC$ cut from a piece of paper; let $D$ be the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$, and fold the paper along $\overline{AD}$ (which is a bisector of $\angle A$). No matter how deep the fold, we have $\angle DAB = \angle DAC = 30^\circ$. On the other hand, the size of $\angle BAC$ changes with the fold: when the paper is unfolded, $\angle BAC = 60^\circ$; when the paper is folded-over, $\angle BAC = 0^\circ$.

So, while the angles between two of the three lines $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ are fixed, the third can be anywhere in the range $0^\circ$ to $60^\circ$. The answer to your question is **No**.

---

However, if you happen to know the angle of the fold, then the size of the missing angle is computable via one of the [Spherical Laws of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) (specifically, the "cosine rule for sides"). Writing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the angles adjacent to the fold-line, and $C$ for the "dihedral" angle of the fold itself, then the angle $\gamma$ between the edges of the paper is given by

$$\cos\gamma = \cos\alpha \cos\beta + \sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos C \qquad (\star)$$

In the example above, we have $\alpha = \beta = 30^\circ$, so that $(\star)$ becomes
$$\cos\gamma = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\cos C = \frac{1}{4}\left(\; 3 + \cos C \;\right)$$

- For un-folded paper, $C = 180^\circ$ so that $\cos\gamma = \frac{1}{4} \left(\; 3 - 1 \;\right) = \frac{1}{2} = \cos 60^\circ$.
- For folded-over paper, $C = 0^\circ$, so that $\cos\gamma = \frac{1}{4} \left(\; 3 + 1 \;\right) = 1 = \cos 0^\circ$.
- For a right-angled fold, $C = 90^\circ$, so that $\cos\gamma = \frac{1}{4} \left(\; 3 + 0 \;\right) = \frac{3}{4} \approx \cos 41.4^\circ$.

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Basic principle: the relative orientation of three lines (through a point) in space has three degrees of freedom, so you can't specify the configuration by two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you had thought about this a little, you would have seen that it is impossible.

Suppose the two given angles are both $90^{\circ}$, so we can take two of the lines to be the $x$ and $y$ axes. Then all we know is that the angle between the third line and the $y$ axis is $90^{\circ}$, which is true for any line in the $xz$ plane. Hence the angle between the third line and the $x$ axis can have *any* value.

There is nothing special about $90^{\circ}$ here. In general, any values for the first two angles will allow a range of values for the third angle.